# Accessing Property of Referenced Model using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am new to automapper and is trying to use the same in my asp.net core project

I have the below models

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }

}

public class Store
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string StoreAddress { get; set; }  
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a view Model as below

```
public partial class StoreDTO
{
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string StoreAddress { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
 
}
```

I had created a Mapping from store to store DTO as below

```
  public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Store, StoreDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyName, source => source.MapFrom(source => source.Company.CompanyName));      
            //I THINK THIS IS WRONG
        }
    }
```

And in the Api Controller Iam mapping as below

```
 var Store = _unitOfWork.Store.GetById(id);
 var getstore = _mapper.Map<StoreDTO>(Store);
```

But the Company Name is alwways returning Null ,What Am I doing wrong in the mapping

Comment: are you sure that Company navigation property is loaded by `_unitOfWork.Store.GetById(id)` or you have lazy loading enabled?

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by Michael , Lazy Loading was not enabled , so the efcore was not able to get the values for Company

I added the below in the Startup class to enable lazy loading in context

```
  services.AddDbContext<AppWebDataContext>(options =>
          options.UseLazyLoadingProxies(). UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("")));
```